# Upload video as unlisted using API v2

Tags: zend-framework, youtube-api

I tried to upload video using API v2. It works but i'd like to set the privacy status of the video as Unlisted. I have the following code to do so:

```
$unlisted = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element('yt:accessControl', 'yt',      'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', '');
$unlisted->setExtensionAttributes(array(
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'list'),
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'permission', 'value' => 'denied')));
$video->setExtensionElements(array($unlisted));
```

This only sets the video as private, not unlisted like i want.
I also tried this but it doesn't work either:

```
        $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
        $status->setPrivacyStatus('unlisted');
```

Any help would be welcome.

PS: The reason I use API v2 is because, correct me if i'm wrong, API v3 doesn't allow browser-based upload. Would be good if someone could clarify that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "unlisted" is not available with the API V2. According to the API V2 documentation, a **private** attribute can be added to the video properties to make a video private otherwise it is public. See the paragraph on https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Response_codes_uploading_videos for **yt:private**.